# Set background color of a specific row within a kivyMD Gridlayout

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm attempting to simulate a datatable with kivyMD.  So far I have the basic layout working which is a scrollable gridlayout holding a bunch of MDFlatbuttons and MDFlatactionbuttons.

[Screen Shot of basic layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWYro.png)

What I'd like to do is hilight a specific row in the gridlayout when the user clicks on it but unsure how to do it.  My first go was to set the background colors of the various widgets but there's gaps between cells.  Is there a way to set the background color for a specific row within the gridlayout ?

kv file:

```
Interface:

<Interface>:
   MDScreen:
        name: "Schedule"
        md_bg_color: "#99ccff"
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: sched_bar
            title: "Delivery Schedule"
            anchor_title: "center"
            elevation: 4
            pos_hint: {"Top": 1}
            y: self.parent.height - self.height
        MDLabel:
            text: "Address"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0,0,0,.83
            x: self.parent.width * .09
            y: self.parent.height * .3
        MDLabel:
            text: "Address"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 102/255,163/255,1,1
            x: self.parent.width * .087
            y: self.parent.height * .302
        MDLabel:
            text: "City"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0,0,0,.83
            x: self.parent.width * .418
            y: self.parent.height * .3
        MDLabel:
            text: "City"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 102/255,163/255,1,1
            x: self.parent.width * .415
            y: self.parent.height * .302
        MDLabel:
            text: "Type"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0,0,0,.83
            x: self.parent.width * .64
            y: self.parent.height * .3
        MDLabel:
            text: "Type"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 102/255,163/255,1,1
            x: self.parent.width * .637
            y: self.parent.height * .302
        MDLabel:
            text: "State"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0,0,0,.83
            x: self.parent.width * .86
            y: self.parent.height * .3
        MDLabel:
            text: "State"
            font_style: "H5"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 102/255,163/255,1,1
            x: self.parent.width * .857
            y: self.parent.height * .302
        ScrollView:
            pos_hint_x: {"center_x": .5}
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 252
            y: 200
            MDGridLayout:
                id: schedule_content
                cols: 4
                size_hint_y: None
                padding: [17,0,17,0]
                adaptive_height: True
        MDFloatLayout:
            MDFloatingActionButton:
                id: sched_but
                icon: "addresses.png"
                elevation: 4
                md_bg_color: "#2196f3"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .10}
                on_release: root.current = "Addresses"
    MDScreen:
        name: "Addresses"
        md_bg_color: "#99ccff"
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: addr_bar
            title: "Addresse Maintenance"
            elevation: 4
            anchor_title: "center"
            pos_hint: {"Top": 1}
            y: self.parent.height - self.height
        MDLabel:
            text: "Where Addresses will show ...."
            font_style: "H6"
            halign: "center"
        MDFloatLayout:
            MDFloatingActionButton:
                id: addr_but
                icon: "grid.png"
                elevation: 4
                md_bg_color: "#2196f3"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .10}
                on_release: root.current = "Schedule"
```

main.py:

```
import platform
import mysql.connector
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, booleanProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.material_resources import dp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
import requests
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRectangleFlatIconButton, MDFloatingActionButton, MDIconButton, MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import MDSmartTile
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import RiseInTransition


Window.size = (550,600)

class Interface(ScreenManager):

    # Properties

    sched_data = ObjectProperty()
    addr_date = ObjectProperty()
    somthing = StringProperty()
    abool = BooleanProperty()

    selected_index = 0
    selected_id = 0
    selected_addr = ""
    selected_stat = ""

    grid_data = []

    if platform.system() == "Windows":

        Window.top = 300
        Window.left = 500

    elif platform.system() == "Linux":

        Window.size = (590,600)
        Window.top = 200
        Window.left = 460


    def reset_background(self):
        pass

    def grid_clicked(self, cell):

        # Determine some things

        if "IMG" in cell.id:

            cell_no = cell.id[cell.id.find("#")+1:cell.id.find("IMG")])

            self.selected_index = cell_no
            self.selected_id = self.grid_data[self.selected_index][0]
            self.selected_addr = self.grid_data[self.selected_index - 3][1]
            self.selected_stat = self.grid_data[self.selected_index][1]

            sched_addr = self.selected_addr
            sched_city = self.grid_data[self.selected_index - 2][1]
            sched_type = self.grid_data[self.selected_index - 1][1]
            sched_stat = self.selected_stat


        else:

            cell_no = int(cell.id[cell.id.find("#")+1:])
            col_no = int(cell.id[cell.id.find("c")+1:cell.id.find("#")])

            self.selected_index = cell_no
            self.selected_id = self.grid_data[self.selected_index][0]

            if col_no == 0:
                self.selected_addr = cell.text
                self.selected_stat = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 3][1]
                sched_addr = self.selected_addr
                sched_city = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 1][1]
                sched_type = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 2][1]
                sched_stat = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 3][1]
            elif col_no == 1:
                self.selected_addr = self.grid_data[self.selected_index - 1][1]
                self.selected_stat = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 2][1]
                sched_addr = self.selected_addr
                sched_city = cell.text
                sched_type = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 1][1]
                sched_stat = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 2][1]
            elif col_no == 2:
                self.selected_addr = self.grid_data[self.selected_index - 2][1]
                self.selected_stat = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 1][1]
                sched_addr = self.grid_data[self.selected_index - 2][1]
                sched_city = self.grid_data[self.selected_index - 1][1]
                sched_type = cell.text
                sched_stat = self.grid_data[self.selected_index + 1][1]


            # Change selection

            if self.selected_index > 0:

                for cell in range(len(self.ids.schedule_content.children)):
                    self.ids.schedule_content.children[cell].md_bg_color = "#99ccff"

            self.ids.schedule_content.children[24].md_bg_color = [0,51/255,153/255,.06]
            self.ids.schedule_content.children[25].md_bg_color = [0,51/255,153/255,.06]
            self.ids.schedule_content.children[26].md_bg_color = [0,51/255,153/255,.06]
            self.ids.schedule_content.children[27].md_bg_color = [0,51/255,153/255,.06]




    def build_grid(self):

        if len(self.sched_data) > 0:

            self.grid_cells = len(self.sched_data) - 1

            child_ctr = 0

            for rec_no in range(len(self.sched_data)):

                #addrfld = MDLabel(text = self.sched_data[rec_no][2], halign="center")
                #addrfld.bind(on_press=self.grid_clicked)

                addrfld = MDFlatButton(id = "r" + str(rec_no) + "c0#" + str(child_ctr),
                                    text = self.sched_data[rec_no][2],
                                    font_size = "16sp",
                                    font_name = "Roboto",
                                    padding = [10,16,0,16],
                                    on_release = self.grid_clicked)

                self.ids.schedule_content.add_widget(addrfld)

                self.grid_data.append([self.sched_data[rec_no][0], self.sched_data[rec_no][2]])

                child_ctr += 1

                #cityfld = MDLabel(text=self.sched_data[rec_no][3], halign="center")

                cityfld = MDFlatButton(id = "r" + str(rec_no) + "c1#"  + str(child_ctr),
                                    text = self.sched_data[rec_no][3],
                                    font_size = "16sp",
                                    font_name = "Roboto",
                                    padding = [40,16,0,16],
                                    on_release = self.grid_clicked)

                self.ids.schedule_content.add_widget(cityfld)

                self.grid_data.append([self.sched_data[rec_no][0], self.sched_data[rec_no][3]])

                child_ctr += 1


                #typefld = MDLabel(text=self.sched_data[rec_no][4], halign="center")

                typefld = MDFlatButton(id = "r" + str(rec_no) + "c2#" + str(child_ctr),
                                    text = self.sched_data[rec_no][4],
                                    font_size = "16sp",
                                    font_name = "Roboto",
                                    padding = [65,16,60,16],
                                    on_release = self.grid_clicked)

                self.ids.schedule_content.add_widget(typefld)

                self.grid_data.append([self.sched_data[rec_no][0], self.sched_data[rec_no][4]])

                child_ctr += 1


                if self.sched_data[rec_no][4] == "Delivery":

                    if self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Pending":
                        stat_icon = "pending_delivery.png"
                    elif self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Completed":
                        stat_icon = "completed_delivery.png"
                    else:
                        stat_icon = "cancelled_delivery.png"

                elif self.sched_data[rec_no][4] == "Dog Walk":

                    if self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Pending":
                        stat_icon = "pending_dog_walk.png"
                    elif self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Completed":
                        stat_icon = "completed_dog_walk.png"
                    else:
                        stat_icon = "cancelled_dog_walk.png"

                elif self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Desk Work":

                    if self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Pending":
                        stat_icon = "pending_desk_work.png"
                    elif self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Completed":
                        stat_icon = "completed_desk_work.png"
                    else:
                        stat_icon = "cancelled_desk_work.png"

                elif self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Other":

                    if self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Pending":
                        stat_icon = "pending_other_work.png"
                    elif self.sched_data[rec_no][6] == "Completed":
                        stat_icon = "completed_other_work.png"
                    else:
                        stat_icon = "cancelled_other_work.png"

                statfld = MDIconButton(
                        id="r" + str(rec_no) + "c2#" + str(child_ctr) + "IMG",
                        icon=stat_icon,
                        icon_size="30sp",
                        on_release=self.grid_clicked)

                self.ids.schedule_content.add_widget(statfld)

                self.grid_data.append([self.sched_data[rec_no][0], self.sched_data[rec_no][6]])

                child_ctr += 1




class DeliverItApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):

        self.title = "D E L I V E R  -  I T   A P P L I C A T I O N"
        self.theme_cls.material_style = "M3"    # you need this to center title in MDTopAppBar

        ScreenManager.transition = RiseInTransition()


        # Pull Data from MySQL Database, create cursors

        try:

            mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                host="localhost",
                user="user",
                password="pwd",
                database="shipping"
            )

            mycursor = mydb.cursor()

            # Address Data

            mycursor.execute("select * from addresses order by id asc")
            self.root.addr_data = mycursor.fetchall()

            # Schedule Data

            mycursor.execute("select * from schedule order by rowid asc")
            self.root.sched_data = mycursor.fetchall()

            mycursor.close()
            mydb.close()

            return 0

        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            raise err


    def on_start(self):
        self.root.build_grid()

DeliverItApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that by using graphics instructions to draw a highlighting rectangle behind the selected row. This can be accomplished with a modified `grid_clicked()` method:

```
def grid_clicked(self, button):
    grid = self.ids.schedule_content
    y = button.center_y  # the y-coord of the center of the Button clicked
    row = 0  # will use this to determine which row was clicked
    curr_top = 0  # this will hold the y-coord of the top of the row clicked
    curr_bottom = grid.padding[1]  # this will hold the y-coord of the bottom of the row clicked on
    while curr_top < grid.height:
        curr_top = curr_bottom + grid._rows[row] + grid.spacing[1]
        if curr_top > y:
            # we are done, this is the row clicked on
            break
        else:
            # increment the row and the bottom of th enext row
            row += 1
            curr_bottom = curr_top
    grid.canvas.before.clear()  # clear any previous highlihjting
    with grid.canvas.before:
        # draw a Rectangle to highlight the row
        Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
        Rectangle(pos=(grid.x, curr_bottom), size=(grid.width, curr_top - curr_bottom))
```

Comment: John ... thank you very much for your input.  I've been banging my head against the wall for days on this and the closest I got was to swap the button image with a background the same color as the hilight.  Works like a charm !

Comment: An additional question if you don't mind ... the statement canvas.before, it's like setting a z order for item before drawing ?

Comment: Yes, there is a `before` and an `after` (as well as the main `canvas`), indicating the order of drawing.